# JavaFx обработка выхода из компонента TextField

Tags: java, javafx

Как отследить в компоненте TextField, что курсор не в нем. Это нужно для проверки значений в реестрации. Или как лучше Это сделать ?

Comment: В любом случаи ставить ActionListener под наведении на поле указателя

Comment: GenCloud, при наведении поставить могу (ставлю через FXML, в OnMouseEntered). Но как поставить, что если я не в TextField значить его обработать.

Comment: `textField.focusedProperty().addListener( (ov, oldV, newV ) -> { if ( !newV ) { /*код*/}});`

Comment: Спасибо, ето то что нужно, только обясните как оно работает. Потому что оно каждьй раз увеличивает количиство проверок. Я вивожу в консоль текст при каждой проверки, и при первом вьходе из текст филд отображает сразу две строки, при втором + 4, тоисть 6. При третем +8, тоисть при третем вьходе из него 13 строк. Почиму так ?